# python - export blender data to excel

Tags: python, excel, export, blender

Okay, so I essentially want to make a pricing calculator that determines the price of an object selected in Blender, based on it's dimensions and volume. I then want to write the calculations to an excel document.

My question is, how would one go about doing this? I was thinking I could do this all in one script run in Blender, but am finding it difficult to import xlwt to write to the excel document.

Should I maybe try calculating the data and saving it to another file and from that file run an external script to write it to an excel document?

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic for the site.  You could make it on topic by asking about a particular problem you are having while implementing specific code (for example importing ```xlwt```)

Comment: Indeed, installing 3rd party modules into the builtin Python interpreter of Blender is a major hassle. Therefore I would suggest the two-phase approach you already outlined: 1) Create a Blender addon that dumps the relevant data in a structured file format (JSON would be easiest, you literally can just dump your Python data structures), CSV or XML would also work. 2) Write a script that performs the price calulations based on that data and writes an Excel sheet using `xlwt`.

Comment: If you struggle with 1) or 2), post a new question and feel free to @mention me.

Comment: Also, if it doesn't matter whether your final output is in `.xls` or `.xlsx` format, I recommend choosing the latter, and using XlsxWriter instead of xlwt.  (I love xlwt; it has served me well for many years, but XlsxWriter is better in almost every conceivable way.)

Comment: It will depend mainly on what you want to do with this. If it is only for you (or staff at work), then you can look into installing python modules that can be used in blender. If you want to share it then you will want to keep it easy to install by using what is available in a standard blender build, csv can be easy to export and opens in excel and other spreadsheets easily.